# Jquery: Automate Mousemove every 20seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousemove

I would like make a script in Jquery that automove my cursor every 20 seconds in a random position of screen.

If is not possible to make in Jquery,how i can make it in Javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't move the user's mouse in JavaScript (or anything built on it)...this would be quite annoying...and used for evil pretty quickly.

For example: Imagine an advertiser's JavaScript moving your mouse to their ad randomly in hopes to get a click.

Comment: Or an advertisement/website that won't let you click on the close or back button. lol Would be pretty funny to watch, though.

Answer (score 4):

The mouse cursor is controlled by the operating system, not the browser, and thus not Javascript/JQuery.

The only way I can think of (maybe others will have better ideas) is to have a separate program that would need to be installed on the client that could possibly communicate, via Javascript, and make it happen, but I doubt that's what you want.